# Kendo Grid Open views for Edit

Tags: kendo-grid

I'm able to load the data in Kendo Grid, and want to implement server Edit.
And created a view and kept on Views/Shared/EditorTemplate/EditEmployee.cshtml.
Can some one help me on how to open that view in new page when user clicks on Edit button.
Controller:

//// GET: EmployeeList/Edit/5

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id, Employee Model)
{
        using (var context = new EmployeeEntities())
        {
            var model = context.Employee.Find(Model.ID);
            return View("EditEmployee");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it completly manual then you can add an event for edit

```
.Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
```

And then redirect there:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    employeeId = $("#EmployeeId").text();
    window.location.href("Employee/Edit/" + editorId);
}
```